# PHP - save the recent 3 viewed cars in DB

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, if-statement, connection

I want to save the car id and a timestamp to a DB. But only the last 3 viewed cars.

**id**  |  **timestamp**    |       **VehicleId**
01 |23-09-21 22:53|XIEKFWSH7S5GESQDGS
02 |23-09-21 24:32|GSTRDDHSDE5GHRDSGD
03 |23-09-21 46:17|LDHGUC86SJNB6%HNSH

Check if there is a old timestamp and overwrite would be preferred (if, then else), as it would generate a lot of data.

Comment: It'd be better if you can add two more columns to your vehicles table 
`updated_timestamp, no_of_views`

on each view of the vehicle update the `no_of_views` and set your `updated_timstamp` on auto-update every time you make changes to the specific car row.

then you can set a simple query and get the most viewed three cars based on `updated_timestamp`

Comment: `ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add the following index to your table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (timestamp);
```

Then, run this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Finally, to deal with data you don't need, you could periodically delete older data from the data, except for the top three most recent rows.

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Biegelesen, How to connect to the DB? The php?
My Table could be **latest**. 
Col 1: VehicleId & 
Col 2: Timestamp.